# Oracle count if column exists in other table with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table

```
COL_A   FROM    TO
------------------
  D1       1     3  
  D2       3     7
```

And also this other table

```
COL_A   VALUE
-------------
    D1      0
    D1      2
    D1      5
    D2      2
    D2      5
    D2      6
```

I want to obtain this. For each row in the first table, count the rows in the second table whose value is less than, between and greater than the FROM and TO columns.

```
COL_A   FROM    TO  LESS_THAN_FROM  BETWEEN_FROM_TO GREATER_THAN_TO
-------------------------------------------------------------------
D1         1     3               1                1               1
D2         3     7               1                2               0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.col_a, t.from, t.to,
       sum(case when o.value < t.from then 1 else 0 end) as less_than,
       sum(case when o.value between t.from and t.to then 1 else 0 end) as in_between,
       sum(case when o.value > t.to then 1 else 0 end) as greater_than
from this_table t join
     other_table o
     on t.col_a = o.col_a
group by t.col_a, t.from, t.to;
```